# Translating "curl -X POST http://something" to pycurl equivalent

Tags: curl, pycurl

I'm a total newbie to curl/pycurl and came across this situation.  Help + additional explanation would be great appreciated!

For whatever reason, "curl -X POST http://something" works for this API service I am experimenting with.  However, I don't really understand why this works as I am not sending any data to the URL?

How would I translate this into pycurl?  pycurl.POSTFIELDs and pycurl.HTTPPOST seem like equivalents to "curl -X POST" but I can't seem to get them to work.

Thank you guys!  First post, longtime lurker.

What would be the pycurl equilavlent of `curl -X POST http://something`

```
c.setopt(pycurl.URL, 'http://something')
c.setopt(pycurl.???, ???)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe. Not sure if there is a better way to force curl not appending any headers.

```
import pycurl

url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'

c = pycurl.Curl()
c.setopt(c.URL, url)
c.setopt(c.CUSTOMREQUEST, 'POST')
c.setopt(c.VERBOSE, True)
c.perform()
c.close()
```